ERROR: Could not import extension autoapi.sphinx (exception: No module named 'autoapi') when attempting to build docs
Im running into an issue sphinx cannot seem to locate the autoAPI extension. For reference I used pip install sphinx-autoapi and I included it in the extensions list in conf.py. Im currently running python 3.10 and sphinx 5.0.0.
Here is the basic structure of my project.
root
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   └── source
│       ├── config.py
│       └── (other documentation files)
└── codebase
    ├── main.py
    └── scripts
        └── (multiple scripts)


I have tried reinstalling, as well as double checking that the extension is included in conf.py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram',
    'autoapi.extension'
]

autoapi_dirs = ['../../codebase']

Any help is much appreciated!
